# Error connecting to PostgreSQL database from Node.js server on localhost. "SSL off"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ssl, docker-compose

My team has been working on a project for a while now and all the sudden the sever is no longer able to communicate with the database.

When spinning up the docker containers the database gives the error

```
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.25.0.4", user "postgres", database "project_db", SSL off
```

We are also no longer able to access the database through the docker cli. It returns this error.

```
root@64cf7d1c02ae:/app# psql -U postgres
psql: error: FATAL:  database "postgres" does not exist
```

The error did not effect one of my teammates, but has persisted for the rest of us. We have tried cloning a new version of the repo from the branch that worked for that teammate, and even sending an exact copy over google dive and we still get the same error.

I was able to upload the version that didn't work for me, but worked for him to Heroku and it worked there.

#### Progress

I've tried following similar questions like [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host) but they have not bee able to solve my problem.

I've tried adding lines to `ph_hba.conf` and `Postgresql.conf` to give the proper access to the server but I still get the same error.

The rest of the answers require that I access my database to add a user, but I can't access the database in the first place.

Comment: the issue related to the access rights. did you check the solution here? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host

Comment: I did look at that but it didn't help. Most of the answers require you to access the database fist, which I can't do, or edit the postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf, but that hasn't worked either.